# Colorize C escape sequence in strings

Tags: listings

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{nimbusmono}

\lstset{
    language=[ANSI]C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
printf("Hello\n");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Is there some nifty way to set the color of the escape sequence `\n` in the string, other than the string color? I tried using `literate` but to no success.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `minted` to colorize listings but this needs to have `pygments` installed (this is a Python package), and also to use `--shellescape` to compile the `TEX` file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
% To test other styles: https://pygments.org/demo/#try
\usemintedstyle{pastie}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
printf("Hello\n");
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know but much of my collegues don't have it installed, so I would like to go for an all-Latex solution.

Comment: Python is coming in Windows too... So it becomes hard to avoid the use of Python... Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow additional characters in your listing, the solution may be as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{nimbusmono}

\lstset{
    language=[ANSI]C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}
}

\lstset{
escapeinside={\%*}{*}
}

\def\n{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\string\n}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
printf("Hello%*\n*");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alas, that's not possible because the code is read in from source files. These source files cannot be changed because they are part of IDE projects I distribute to students.